# webpack-dev-server not working for my express routes

Tags: vue.js, routes, webpack-dev-server

I'm new to stackexchange and webpack. I'm trying to set up a development server using webpack-dev-server and my express server. I'm using webpack to build the entire back-end and front-end and it works perfectly, yet the routes in my server code do not work when I try to use webpack's development server. I tried for days to get this to work and searched the internet for a solution, however, my skill level is just not high enough to deduce a solution from available online help, so now I'm here.

Inside my webpack.config.js there is a server config that will run on node and a client config that will run on the front-end. I played with the devServer.proxy settings to no avail (I don't seem to understand what exactly is going on with these settings).

If you want to take a look at the whole source code: https://github.com/spencel/gwpp-v1-dev.git

[here is what my project tree looks like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gu5MX.png)

Comment: Uhh...You've leaked your database credentials in that repository. I'd delete that repository immediately and change your credentials.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy thank you for the alert. how would i go about securing database credentials in the server code?

Comment: @spence Use environment variables.

Comment: @EricGuan thank you for the help. I went ahead learned how to use process.env with the dotenv npm package. I greatly appreciate the opportunity to learn.